# Listing files with name starting with either a capital letter or a specific number (e.g. 3)

Tags: linux, wildcards

I want to list files with names starting with either a capital letter or a specific number (e.g. 3).

I tried something like

```
ls ~/etc/[[:upper:]][3].*
```

but doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `~/etc/[[:upper:]][3].*` matches any name in the `etc` subdirectory in your home directory that starts with an upper-case letter, followed the character `3` and a dot.

The subpattern `[3]` matches a `3`, only, and I assume you've used `.*` as a regular expression, possibly?  That `.*` regular expression is more or less the same as `*` in a filename globbing pattern (the shell does not use regular expressions for globbing). As a globbing pattern, `.*` would match a substring that starts with a dot.

The pathname `~/etc/A3.txt` would match your original pattern, for example, while `~/etc/A3` would not match as it lacks the dot after the `3`.

If you want to match files in `~/etc` that start with either an upper-case letter or the character `3`, use the pattern

```
~/etc/[[:upper:]3]*
```